# Is it unprofessional to be motivated by personal concerns?

Tags: professionalism

On p.3 of the [UN Core Values and Standards of Conducts](http://www.un.org/en/ethics/pdf/WorkinTogetherGuide_en.pdf) it reads

> Be motivated by professional objectives rather than personal concerns

Could someone please explain, why the UN deems motivation by professional objectives more professional and give examples for professional objectives vs personal concerns.

Answer (score 6):

The personal concerns they are likely referring to are things like:

- *empire-building* - creating a team or division within an organisation as a power-play rather than with any specific business or organisational need in mind;
- *ass-covering* - working to make sure that you don't get blamed for !@#$ rather than working to prevent !@#$ from happening;
- *helping yourself* - using your work (and work from your team/staff) for your own benefit and/or the benefit of people close to you.

That's not so say that you *can't* have a personal motivation in doing something - but if you aren't able to provide a professional objective, then you are not acting professionally.

Comment: Yes - I think the differentiation is being motivated by "personal concerns" that may be in direct conflict with the mission/vision of the employer - as the examples you gave would be for the UN - versus "personal concerns" that would be inline with the goals of the employer: helping protect human rights, end world hunger, etc etc